# VBA SAP "user defined type not defined"

Tags: vba, sap-gui

While trying to Vba to automate some SAP transactions I'm getting the error "user defined type not defined". I think I should have "SAP Gui API" in my references, but I can't find it there anymore. This used to work before I restarted my computer. Any ideas?

```
 Option Explicit
Public SapGuiAuto, WScript, msgcol   
Public Application  As GuiApplication      // I get the error here /// 
Public Connection As GuiConnection
Public session As GuiSession


Sub Processing ()

Dim W_Obj1, W_Obj2, W_Obj3, W_Obj4, iRow
Dim W_Func
Dim W_Src_Ord
Dim W_Ret As Boolean
Dim itemcount As Integer
Dim itemmax As Integer
Dim objSheet As Worksheet
Const startrow As Integer = 7 

Set objSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet


Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = Application.Children(0)
Set session = Connection.Children(0)


If Not IsObject(Application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = Application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").Maximize
For iRow = startrow To objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
   
// SAP script    
Next   
End Sub
```

Comment: You must install SAP GUI for Windows with the SAP GUI Scripting component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What type of object is returned by GetObject("SAPGUI")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277546/what-type-of-object-is-returned-by-getobjectsapgui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the following changes, then it should work.

for example:

```
'Option Explicit
' Public SapGuiAuto, WScript, msgcol   
' Public Application  As GuiApplication      // I get the error here /// 
' Public Connection As GuiConnection
' Public session As GuiSession


Sub Processing ()

Dim W_Obj1, W_Obj2, W_Obj3, W_Obj4, iRow
Dim W_Func
Dim W_Src_Ord
Dim W_Ret As Boolean
Dim itemcount As Integer
Dim itemmax As Integer
Dim objSheet As Worksheet
Const startrow As Integer = 7 

Set objSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet


Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SapApplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SapApplication.Children(0)
Set session = Connection.Children(0)

'If Not IsObject(Application) Then
'   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
'   Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
'End If
'If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
'   Set Connection = Application.Children(0)
'End If
'If Not IsObject(session) Then
'   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
'End If
'If IsObject(WScript) Then
 '  WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
 '  WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
 'End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").Maximize
For iRow = startrow To objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

 // SAP script    
Next   
End Sub
```

Regards, ScriptMan